# Devise: How do I call `new_confirmation_path()` from a view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I see this `new_confirmation_path(resource_name)` called in generated Devise views.

I want to call this a custom view. The user isn't logged in.

`new_confirmation_path(resource_name)` is the way to generate a link to new confirmations page.

What is a `resource_name`?

How do I get it?

Is it possible to get it, in another (non-Devise) view?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`resource_name` in Devise is typically the name of the resource that you passed to `devise_for` in your `config/routes.rb`. So if you use `devise_for(:users)` it will be `:user`.

```
class DeviseController < Devise.parent_controller.constantize
  def resource_name
    devise_mapping.name
  end
end
```

Devise uses the same views / controllers for many different models and does so through this mapping created in the routes which is injected into `request.env`.

If you know the model name you can also just use the named route helpers created for your app which would typically be `new_user_confirmation_path`.